# PAM authentication error when trying to log in via SSH to FreeBSD on VirtualBox

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, freebsd

I have FreeBSD 12.2 installed on VirtualBox 6.1 with the "Bridged Adapater" mode enabled to test Apache via browser by following the IP address I receive by the `ifconfig em0 inet` command (and it works).

Now I'm trying to log in via Putty SSH using the IP address. But when I type my root password, I receive the error

> host sshd[1320]: PAM: Authentication error for root from ...

In my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file I've changed the line `PermitRootLogin` to `yes` and uncommented it and the line `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes`. However, I'm not sure they are the lines I should to uncomment. I've restarted the SSH by the command `service sshd restart`. But I still receive the same authentication error.

How to enable SSH?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify two files (uncomment and enable options):

```
vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config

PasswordAuthentication yes
```

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then, restart the sshd deamon:

```
service sshd restart
```